# Throwing a bomb LibGDX Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d, physics

I am trying to create game where somenone throw a bomb.  I am wondering how I can have an bomb react in a way that is represented by the following picture :  [image]

Is there are any tools in Box2D that can help me achieve this?

Comment: What exactly about that are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: All you need is to give the bomb a Box2d body, make sure your sprite updates with that body's position, have gravity, and apply an upward force (like throwing it). Box2D does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Give the ball some restitution (box2d property) having a rigid circle body attached, and later, simply apply some force to it ;) It will work as shown (of course, u should be having some bounding box)

Could give you currect code if u needed :)

## code:

```
Body ball;

BodyDef _b = new BodyDef();
_b.position.set(new Vector2(0, 0));   //your wish
_b.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

CircleShape ball_shape = new CircleShape();
ball_shape.setRadius(0.5f);

FixtureDef ball_physic_property = new FixtureDef();
ball_physic_property.density = 0.1f;       //your wish
ball_physic_property.restitution = 0.8f;   //your wish
ball_physic_property.friction = 0.5f;      //your wish
ball_physic_property.shape = ball_shape;

ball = world.createBody(_b);
ball.createFixture(ball_physic_property);
ball_shape.dispose();
```

### I believe you got some basics in libgdx box2d :) this should sort you out :)

For the bomb thing, you could make a sprite follow the rigidbody's position ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer! It would be great if you could share code you have :)

Comment: Thanks :) I have done that in my constructor. But problem is how I need to move my bomb up( increase y-axis) and to the right ( increase x-axis) and then just decrease y-axis that my bomb could move down.

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer if it proves to solve your problem?

Comment: Apply ball's position to the bomb sprite ;)